# JPA merge not working in ApplicationListener but working in Controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm having some weird problem with my JPA merge function. I am trying to get the last login times of my users and I want to update the user in the database when they login.

The application listener for successful login events:

```
@Component
public class SuccessLoginApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>{
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent loginEvent) {
        User user = (User) loginEvent.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        user.setLastLogin(100000);
        userDao.merge(user);
    }
}
```

UserDao

```
@Transactional
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDao{
    protected EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public User merge(User user){
        return em.merge(user);
    }
}
```

Because the actual code includes a bunch of interfaces, other methods etc., the above code should include all that is important relevant to this question, I hope I did not forget something.

When I do the following in a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class ProfileController {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String profile(Model model){
        User user = getCurrentlyLoggedInUser();
        user.setLastLogin(1000000);
        userDao.merge(user);
        return "account/profile";
    }
}
```

Everything works just as I would expect it to work, the database gets successfully changed to the new lastLogin value.

The problem is when a successful login happens, even tho I do exactly the same as in the controller, the database does **not** get updates... I have confirmed that the methods are actually called (`onApplicationEvent`, `merge`).

I am absolutely clueless why it **doesn't** work in the `ApplicationListener`, but it **does** work in the controller. Am I not understanding something about the merge function properly?

I read the following: When you call merge, a managed entity is returned and changes to the managed entity are supposedly updated in the database, so I've also tried the following in the `userDao`:

```
public User merge(User user){
    User user = em.merge(user);
    user.setLastLogin(100000);
}
```

The same thing happens here, when the merge function is called from the ApplicationListener, nothing is changed in the database, but when it is called from the Controller, the field is correctly set to 100000.

Thanks for reading, hope you can help! :)

Comment: Wild guess you are loading the same component twice and you have a `<tx:annotation-driven />` only in the context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: @M.Deinum that was a really accurate wild guess, that was exactly the case, the problem is solved, thanks! (im not sure how to handle this when a comment is an answer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general when transactions aren't working in one case and they work in another you have multiple instances of a component. One has AOP applied an the other hasn't.

This generally comes from having the same `<context:component-scan />` in both the context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`. The one loaded in the context that has the additional `<tx:annotation-driven />` will have working transactions the other won't.

Your `ContextLoaderListener` should load all beans that are global for the application (services, daos, datasources etc. and have transactions applied). Your `DispatcherServlet` should generally only load web related things (controllers, view resolvers etc.).